# MySql получение дерева связей в глубину, между записями

Tags: php, mysql

возник вопрос при работе с графами, можно ли в MySql получить все связанные записи так сказать в глубину до самого конца?

К примеру есть 3 таблицы "t1", "t2", "t3" 
Тип связи, "t1" один ко многим  "t2", "t3"
t1 содержит первичный ключ, t2 и t3 вторичные ключи.

Как в MySql можно получить все возможные связи.

MySql версия 5.7

Прошу показать на примере, если это возможно.

Заранее спасибо!

[image: то что я хочу получить в результате запроса]

Comment: Лучшее решение - обновиться до 8 версии. Ну или писать хранимую процедуру. Это на текущей структуре. Которая, судя по тому, что заданный вопрос вообще возник, далека от оптимума...

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант не подходит.